Implementing Firebase Notifications - Optimizing for least # of calls
I'm trying to implement a notification system using Firebase/FCM and I'm realizing that a timezone-aware, cron-initiated implementation to filter users that need to be notified ends up generating a huge # of reads really fast and I'd love to know what's the canonical way to do this since it seems like a bog standard feature that has been built 100s of times.
User feature: Choose days of the week and a time when you'd like to be sent a reminder notification.
Implementation: There's a JSON object that contains userid keys and values that contain the notification day/time/timezone.
{
  userid1: {
    days: ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday'],
    time: '20:00',
    timezone: 'America/New_York',
  },
  userid2: {
    days: ['Sunday','Tuesday','Wednesday'],
    time: '21:00',
    timezone: 'Europe/London',
  },
  ...
}

By saving the time in the backend as time + timezone, I don't have to worry about things like daylight savings.
Lastly, I can create a scheduled function to run every 15 mins, query for all the user records that match the time/timezone and send them a notification.
The Problem
Because the time data is stored separately as time + timezone, I'll end up querying all the user records for each call, every 15 minutes to see if they match the current time window. For a 1000 users who need to be notified, I end up making 96000 (1000 * 4 * 24) calls a day which is ridiculous given the pricing.
Edit:
It seems that my problem description might be unclear:
Each k/v pair for notification day times contains the Day of the week, timezone and the local time .
This local time + timezone needs to be converted to absolute UTC terms before it's queryable. And that conversion cannot always be done in advance because it changes depending on daylight savings changes.

Instead of making one query for each of your 1000 users, why don't you make just one query that covers all 1000 users, and see which ones end up with a message for the current window.  You haven't said anything about your database or data structure, so maybe those need to be improved to support this.

@DougStevenson I think you misunderstood. There will 1 query every 15 minutes FOR ALL 1000 users. But it'll have to fetch every single record back to see if the times fall in the window. If Daylight savings etc werent an issue, I could just put the time in the query and only fetch the relevant users. But because of DST etc. you have to check each record, evaluate the "what does 8pm in london mean in absolute UTC terms", compare it to current time window and decide to skip or process the record.

Maybe precompute and store a more queryable value that doesn't involve timezone, such as unix time in UTC.  What you are trying to query now is just not suitable for the task at hand.  I don't think you're going to find any "bog standard" workarounds here,.

"that conversion cannot always be done in advance because it changes depending on daylight savings changes" The daylight savings changes are known quite well in advance for most places. It's non-trivial of course as timezone changes are complex by nature, but the necessary information is available and there are libraries for most popular platforms.

@DougStevenson , Frank van Puffelen I understand what y'all are saying and 100% believe you but but part of me is finding it hard to believe because this is a very common feature built across many popular apps. I don't suppose they're all making highly specific optimizations based on the daylight savings times for very country, no? Besides, these changes are legislation dependent and possible to be out of date. In the last decade alone, Azerbaijan, Iran, Jordan, Namibia, Russia, Samoa, Syria, Turkey and Uruguay have all ended their seasonal time changes. I suppose a non-FB solution makes sense

To clarify on @DougStevenson's comment "Maybe precompute and store a more queryable value that doesn't involve timezone, such as unix time in UTC". Yes, this is likely what I'll end up doing but the precompute will have to be run every day because the moment a daylight savings change happens, the precompute value will be wrong. Frank's suggestion is to only run this precompute on the days when those daylight savings changes happen and I think technically do-able but pretty gnarly to keep correct.
